# Changing the alignment and background color of specific text in a table

Tags: html, background, alignment

I am trying to change the alignment (center) and background color of only certain pieces of text within a table-cell. I know how to do it for the whole cell, but how do you do it for only specific pieces of text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<td>
<div style="text-align: right;">will be aligned right</div>
<div style="background-color: #999;">will have a gray background</div>
</td>
```

It's better if you do this properly through a css stylesheet, this is just for illustrative purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the text to which you are interested in adding css in a span.  Note that if you want the text centered in a column you probabaly want to apply "align:center" to the <td> and not the span.

For example:

```
<tr>
<td><span class="classForEverythingButCentering">not centered</span></td>
<td style="align:center">centered</td>
<td class="centered">differently centered
(if you setup a class named .centered or perhaps td.centered).</td>
</tr>
```